# How to create HTML drop-down with all options showing by default?

Tags: html, forms, drop-down-menu

I guess it's not really a drop-down but it looks like a drop-down with all the values "selected" or viewable on page-load. I am not sure of the correct HTML to create it. Here's a picture.[image: picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the `size` attribute of the `select` element.

If the value of the size attribute is greater than 1, then all options are displayed in a scrollable pane. Otherwise you get the classic dropdown.

```html
<select size="5">
  <option>Report A</option>
  <option>Report B</option>
  <option>Report C</option>
  <option>Report D</option>
</select>
```

Alternatively, you can use the `multiple` attribute which will set `size` to a default value of 4.